# shows error during the build after adding ng-bootstrap in project

Tags: ng-bootstrap

ERROR in node_modules/@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/accordion/accordion.d.ts:191:9 - error TS1086: An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context.

191     set ngbPanelToggle(panel: NgbPanel);

Comment: Can you show how you're importing bootstrap and how you're using the accordion?

Comment: I followed the steps what https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/getting-started this site says.

Comment: It's a angular powered bootstrap. I followed all the step described but while building the app, it's shows error

Comment: Can you show how you're importing bootstrap and how you're using the accordion?